# Laravel portal working perfectly on Local and Another Server too but not on mine

Tags: php, laravel

I've a Laravel portal which I exported from another server and working perfectly on my localhost but when I tried to move it into another server the pages are working fine but whenever I'm trying to submit a form it is showing 419 | Page Expired Error and I've already added @csrf in my form and one more thing when I trying to directly access the admin page the page also not showing the session message (access denied) and invalid details message. It just blink with a message Redirecting to my-home-page-link. Can anybody help me with this.

I've tried to clear routes of my portal but nothing is working.

Comment: Open incognito mode and try to run the same form, I think its a session issue where you have a cached token from a Local instance of your project.

Comment: Are you sure you're not using internet explorer?

Comment: @dz0nika I've tried on another browser and in private window too, even I've tried it in another device too with another network. But nothing is working

Comment: @IbrahimHammed Naah I'm using chrome and microsoft edge. But seems I can't find any solution. 

Comment: Are you using sanctum for authentication?

Comment: No I'm using custom session based authentication but a thing need to discuss my api.php have a route like:

Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Comment: @VinayMunjal Did u run ```php artisan config:cache```?

Comment: And the database has been setup? all migrations run?

Comment: @VinayMunjal Can you share your route file? I had the same problem in the past. In my route file, I have given except parameters to my routes that I use with resources. Could it be related to this?

Comment: @SemihSAHIN Yeah for sure but how can I share my file. There is a huge lines of code in it.

Comment: @VinayMunjal For just one example, you can share the section of a little that covers your request for a form.

Comment: Route::get('/',[HomeController::class,'login']);
    Route::get('/login',[HomeController::class,'login']);
    Route::get('/logout',[HomeController::class,'logout']);
    Route::post('login',[HomeController::class,'auth'])->name('auth');
    Route::post('login-with-auth',[HomeController::class,'loginWithAuth'])->name('login-with-auth');

Comment: Please check if your first route is duplicated, it should fire an exception.
In addition, can you tell us how is your app managing sessions? If your setup is using DB you should try to change to file
In your .env file you should have something like `SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120`

Answer (score 2):

**Please make sure you have @csrf or {{ csrf_field() }} in your form.**

The Session Expired or 419 Page Expired error message in Laravel comes up because somewhere your csrf token verification fails which means the `App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class` middleware is already turned on. In the form the @csrf blade directive is already added, which should be fine as well.

Comment: As I already mentioned I added @csrf in my code.

Comment: If incase it is an ajax request on load, inn addition to checking for the CSRF token as a POST parameter, the App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken middleware will also check for the X-CSRF-TOKEN request header. You could, for example, store the token in an HTML meta tag:

<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

Comment: Try to disable VerifyCsrfToken and check if your case works fine. Might be something wrong with middle wares.

Comment: @NomanYousaf I tried by commenting the verifycsrftoken line in kernel.php but nothing worked. 

Comment: @vinay That's strange try to change session driver maybe something wrong with session managing.

Comment: in config/session.php??? and replace with what?

Comment: try database and for this you need session table to be exist into database as well:

To generate the table try calling the php artisan session:table then, migrate the table php artisan migrate this will create a session table for you.

Comment: @NomanYousaf Now page expired problem has been solved but now routes are not working

Comment: that shouldn't be the case, what are you getting for routes error 403 or 401 or 400?